# Unable to find element by xpath "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

First time using Selenium, currently trying to upload a TCX file downloaded from one site to another and running into sticking problem clicking the upload button

Have tried utilising the basic find_element commands and have also used;

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uploadFile"]/form/input[3]')))
```

have also tried

```py
driver.switch_to_frame

time.sleep(2)

upload = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='uploadFile']/form/input[3]").click()
```

Comment: In your bottom example you're missing a `[` right before `@id`. Can you successfully find `//*[@id="uploadFile"]`? That's a much more concrete example to make sure there's not something else going wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @AlexSimcock do you think people have credentials to log in to that sited and reproduce your problem? please read [mcve]

Comment: @orde, this is HTML for the particular upload button I'm trying to hit;

`<input class="files" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" type="file">`